# How to execute my playwright tests in Azure DevOps Test Plans

Tags: azure-devops, playwright, playwright-test

I am trying to use Azure DevOps TestPlans in our organisation but I didn't find any option to run my Playwright tests in Azure Test Plans.

Any suggestions if I can somehow manage to execute my playwright tests?

I am expecting to run my automated tests (playwright tests) in Azure DevOps Test Plans.

I tried creating a release pipeline and was able to execute my tests there but when I am trying to execute tests using Test Plans, I am getting this message:

[image]

Comment: This has been requested as feature https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/14839 and there is one comment in the issue. You can check that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot able to execute the playwright test cases using Test Plan as we are not able to link playwright test case with azure test case. you have to execute the whole test cases using the command line or you can group test cases and execute the group test cases.

For Group test case execution: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-annotations#group-tests

For execution using command line: npx playwright test --workers=4 --retries=1